# merge SAS char to num

Tags: sas

```
libname Prob 'Y:\alsdkjf\alksjdfl';
```

the geoid here is char I wanna convert to num to be able to merge by id;

```
 data Problem2_1; 
 set Prob.geocode;     
 id = substr(GEOID, 8, 2);
 id = input(id, best5.);  
 output;
 run;
```

geoid here is numeric;

```
data Problem2_2; c
set Prob.households;
id = GEOID;
output;
run;

data Problem2_3;
merge Problem2_1
Problem2_2 ;
by    ID;
run;

proc print data =  Problem2_3;
```

*ERROR: Variable geoid has been defined as both character and numeric.
*ERROR: Variable id has been defined as both character and numeric.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could replace these two lines:

```
id = substr(GEOID, 8, 2);
id = input(id, best5.);
```

With:

```
id = input(substr(GEOID, 8, 2), best.);
```

This would mean that both merge datasets contain numeric id variables.

Answer (score 0):

SAS requires the linking id to be same data type. This means that you have to convert the int to string or vice versa. Personally, I prefer to convert to numeric when ever it is possible.

A is a worked out example:

```
/*Create some dummy data for testing purposes:*/
data int_id;
    length id 3 dummy $3;
    input id dummy;
    cards;
    1 a
    2 b
    3 c
    4 d
    ;
run;

data str_id;
    length id $1 dummy2 $3;
    input id dummy2;
    cards;
    1 aa
    2 bb
    3 cc
    4 dd
    ;
run;

/*Convert string to numeric. Int in this case.*/
data str_id_to_int;
    set str_id;
    id2 =id+0; /* or you could use something like  input(id, 8.)*/
    /*The variable must be new. id=id+0 does _not_ work.*/

    drop id; /*move id2->id */
    rename id2=id;
run;

/*Same, but other way around. Imho, trickier.*/
data int_id_to_str;
    set int_id;
    id2=put(id, 1.); /*note that '1.' refers to lenght of 1 */
    /*There are other ways to convert int to string as well.*/
    drop id;
    rename id2=id;
run;

/*Testing. Results should be equivalent */
data merged_by_str;
    merge str_id(in=a) int_id_to_str(in=b);
    by id;
    if a and b;
run;

data merged_by_int;
    merge int_id(in=a) str_id_to_int(in=b);
    by id;
    if a and b;
run;
```

Answer (score -1):

For `Problem2_1`, if your substring contains only numbers you can coerce it to numeric by adding zero. Something like this should make ID numeric and then you could merge with `Problem2_2`.

```
data Problem2_1; 
set Prob.geocode;     
temp = substr(GEOID, 8, 2);
id = temp + 0;  
drop temp;
run;
```

EDIT:
Your original code originally defines ID as the output of substr, which is character. This should work as well:

```
data Problem2_1; 
set Prob.geocode;     
temp = substr(GEOID, 8, 2);
id = input(temp, 8.0);  
drop temp;
run;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks now there is only one error message....*ERROR: Variable id has been defined as both character and numeric.

Comment: is ID still character in `problem2_2`?

Comment: VARIABLE     TYPE     DESCRIPTION                                         EXAMPLE
GEOID           NUM     1- or 2-digit Geography Code                  34
TOTHOUSE   NUM     Total Households                                     3064645
UNMARRIED NUM T   Total Unmarried-Partner Households     151318

Comment: There isn't already a variable called `ID` in either data set? Once a variable is defined with a type you can't overwrite it, afaik, hence why I used the temp variable above

Comment: ok. if you run `proc contents` on the two original datasets (prob.geocode and prob.households), what type is GEOID in each?

Comment: so `temp = substr(GEOID, 8, 2);` should be returning a character variable with the two specified digits. Are all of those digits numbers? You could try doing a `proc freq` on temp and making sure there aren't any instances with non-numeric characters.

Comment: geoid in geocode is like 04000US34... where geoid in  households is 34... thats why im just getting the last 2 for geo id so I can merge it with household... (like joining in SQL)

Comment: then I'm not sure what's up - if I use the `input` approach with some dummy data on my end I output a numeric variable, which is why i asked if maybe you had some other characters in those digits. sorry :-(

Comment: HI Craig can you help me with this

Comment: suppose an ID is like this 

2:14:58 PM: 1530M 

 4568F 
 43m 
 x213f 

 I just wana get the numeric part 
 they are not equal length 
 some has prefix 
 of x 
 and the M and F are the gender

Comment: data Problem3;
    set Prob.sbp;
          new_ID = upcase(id);
    ID = cat(id); 
    sex = substr(right of = id,1);  *M or F only 
    *maxvisit;
run;


Title 'SBP';
proc print data =  Problem3;
run;